# Vim saved file not updating on webpage

Tags: bash, vim, swap, cache, file-sharing

I am attempting to update an HTML file on my server, but when I do so it doesn't appear to be updating, but rather, serves an old copy instead. I went through the usual process of pressing :w and hitting enter (not in insert mode! :P) but still nothing.

Also, whenever I try to edit the file I get a message saying the .swp file is already in use by another process, but I only have one bash shell open (connected on through PuTTY)...

I have tried a hard reload and cache clean but to no avail. I have already tried in another browser, which didn't help.

I have also tried removing all of the swap files and pasting in the correct file from a version stored in notepad, but the file still will not update.

Any ideas guys/gals?

Footnote: Full error message received when attempting to edit .html file:

```
E325: ATTENTION
Found a swap file by the name ".index.html.swp"
          owned by: orderof3   dated: Mon Apr 25 04:48:09 2016
         file name: ~orderof3/public_html/Inviqa/TechPt1/index.html
          modified: no
         user name: orderof3   host name: e9.ehosts.com
        process ID: 66769
While opening file "index.html"
             dated: Mon Apr 25 11:32:56 2016
      NEWER than swap file!

(1) Another program may be editing the same file.  If this is the case,
    be careful not to end up with two different instances of the same
    file when making changes.  Quit, or continue with caution.
(2) An edit session for this file crashed.
    If this is the case, use ":recover" or "vim -r index.html"
    to recover the changes (see ":help recovery").
    If you did this already, delete the swap file ".index.html.swp"
    to avoid this message.

Swap file ".index.html.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is a static file, most likely your browser doesn't really retrieve the new file, you can check that by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> while clicking refresh (at least in Firefox).

If that doesn't work, it is probably your webserver doesn't notice the change in that case reloading the webserver is normally enough. E.g for apache2

```
service  apache2 reload
```

or

```
systemctl reload apache2.service
```

In extreme cases, you might need to restart the webserver. In any case `:w` in `vi` saves the file, if `vi` had problems doing so it would notify you.

Comment: I have updated my answer with further details... now the entire contents of the .html file have disappeared... :/

Comment: Looks like you are already editing that file in another terminal (or in a session that was interrupted)

Comment: I only have one terminal. I use PuTTY and I have never opened more than one instance of it at any one time. I did have a session that closed itself with the message ```[1]+ Kill```, though...